How to simultaneously update input value from props and from user inputting (Vue 3, Composition API)?
When I'm using 'ref' - value doesn't updating from props.
When using 'toRef' - value doesn't updating from user inputting.
Watch, computed - the same...
I was only able to solve this by introducing an additional variable and using watch method:
<template>
    <input
        v-model="inputVal"
        @change="$emit('change-val', inputVal)"
        type="text"
    >
</template>

<script>
import { ref, toRef, watch } from 'vue'

export default {
    name: 'RefInput',
    props: {
        val: [String, Number, Array]
    },
    setup(props) {
        const propsVal = toRef(props, 'val')
        const inputVal = ref(propsVal.value)

        watch(propsVal, (propsVal) => {
            inputVal.value = propsVal
        })

        return{
            inputVal
        }
    }
}
</script>


The Vue documentation on v-model explains how this is usually done.  With <script setup> we just use defineModel macro, but with setup function you can still implement what defineModel does "under the hood" which is how we used to always do it before defineModel was introduced in Vue 3.4

Name the prop modelValue
Bind the prop to the input's value (one-way binding, because props are read only)
Emit update:modelValue with the the event.target.value when the input updates.

<template>
    <input
        :value="modelValue"
        @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
        type="text"
    >
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'RefInput',
    props: {
        modelValue: [String, Number]
    },
    setup() {}
}
</script>

Playground example
This will not work with an array since you have to access values in an array using an index first, so you'd need more code if that's really a value you expect the prop to have.
Edit:
Addressing the comment using store code:
Pinia Playground example

Almost. But the situation is a little more complicated - in props I transferring a computed property.
i.e. :val="store.data[store.changeable + 'Percent'] + '%'"
And in callback respectively @change-val="(val) => store.data[store.changeable + 'Percent'] = val.replace('%', '')"

It's doing more JS in the template than I'd usually recommend, but I don't see a problem with it.  However I also don't know exactly what these values mean or how your store is defined.  It would've been relevant information to put with the question.  See the new link added to the bottom of my answer showing how I think this store code could work.

That's what I need!
I was confused by v-model into which an expression cannot be passed. Thanks a lot!

P.S. Does the property have to be called modelValue?

For component v-model to work it does require the prop in the child be named "modelValue".  You can use other names, but then v-model must be modified, e.g. if the prop is named "val" then the parent component must use v-model:val, which is talked about here in the docs

And I checked - it works with arrays too. By default, the array in the input el is displayed as strings separated by commas.
